# Unable to rename Bluetooth Headphones on mac

Tags: mac, bluetooth

I opened Bluetooth preferences, right clicked on device and selected rename. I provided new name in the textbox and clicked on `rename` button. It did not change the name. I tried like 100 times, it didn't work. I am on macOS Sierra 10.12.5.

Comment: same here. macbook pro Sierra. headphones can be renamed on iMAC but not this laptop. i do not see any answers here or in other related threads. i tried connected and not connected. i tried closing B pref and re-opening. it just will not allow rename of blutooth device despite offering the rename feature and apparently accepting the new name when i submit it.